# Count number of NULL values in a row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to count the number of `NULL` values in a row.

For example:

```
Name    Col1    Col2      Col3     Col4 | ansCol
abc     null   a@c.com    null     null | 3
bbc     null    null      null     null | 4
```

In this example the answer is simple:

```
SELECT *,
(CASE WHEN Name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN Col1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +       
CASE WHEN Col2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +       
CASE WHEN Col3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +       
CASE WHEN Col4 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ansCol
```

The question becomes more complex when we have a very wide table, more than 10 columns. If I try to use the method that was shown I get the following error:

> Msg 125, Level 15, State 4, Line 13
>   Case expressions may only be nested to level 10.

Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: I used Case for 13 columns and there is no issue ?
Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader Please leave such a comment under the question and not under everyone's answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Done.

Comment: where is nested ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to above, a potential approach would be to use `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` functionality.

Let's first create the table and insert the data per the question:

```
/* Create table */
CREATE TABLE so_40957006 (
    [name]  VARCHAR(24),
    [col1]  VARCHAR(24),
    [col2]  VARCHAR(24),
    [col3]  VARCHAR(24),
    [col4]  VARCHAR(24)
)

/* Insert data */
INSERT INTO so_40957006 VALUES('abc', null, 'a@c.com', null, null)
INSERT INTO so_40957006 VALUES('bbc', null, null, null, null)
```

What we will first do is create an identity table so this way we can uniquely identify each row of data and insert the data.

```
/* Create identity table */
CREATE TABLE so_40957006_id (
    [lid]   INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [name]  VARCHAR(24),
    [col1]  VARCHAR(24),
    [col2]  VARCHAR(24),
    [col3]  VARCHAR(24),
    [col4]  VARCHAR(24)
)

/* Insert data into table */
INSERT INTO so_40957006_id 
SELECT 
  ISNULL([name], 1) AS [name]
 ,ISNULL([col1], 1) AS [col1]
 ,ISNULL([col2], 1) AS [col2]
 ,ISNULL([col3], 1) AS [col3]
 ,ISNULL([col4], 1) AS [col4]
FROM so_40957006
```

Note that in the process we have converted any of the columns that are null to a value of 1 by using `IsNull`.   The table now looks like below.

```
lid name    col1    col2    col3    col4
1   abc     1       a@c.com 1       1
2   bbc     1       1       1       1
```

With this, we can now use `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` to *verticalize* the data. For example, running the query below

```
SELECT [lid], [cols], [val]
FROM
    (SELECT [lid], [name], [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4]
        FROM so_40957006_id) p
UNPIVOT
    (val FOR cols IN 
    ([name], [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4])
) AS unpvt
```

provides you with the vertical output of:

```
lid cols    val
1   name    abc
1   col1    1
1   col2    a@c.com
1   col3    1
1   col4    1
2   name    bbc
2   col1    1
2   col2    1
2   col3    1
2   col4    1
```

Since the values you want to count (i.e. the `NULL`s) have a value of 1, you can just run a `GROUP BY` + `SUM` statement:

```
SELECT [lid], SUM(cast([val] as integer)) as CountNulls
  FROM (
    SELECT [lid], [cols], [val]
    FROM
        (SELECT [lid], [name], [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4]
           FROM so_40957006_id) p
    UNPIVOT
     (val FOR cols IN 
       ([name], [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4])
    ) AS unpvt
) a 
WHERE ISNUMERIC([val]) = 1
GROUP BY [lid]
```

with the output

```
lid CountNulls
1   3
2   4
```

With the `[lid]` you can `JOIN` this output back to the original table to generate your result set.

Answer (score 5):

The code in your question doesn't have any *nested* case so you should be able to chain together more than 10 with addition just fine.

But some other possibilities are...

If all the columns have the same datatype you could use ([Demo](http://rextester.com/AQZV88112))

```
SELECT *,
       ansCol = (SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(C) FROM (VALUES(c1),(c2),(c3),(c4)) V(C))
FROM   t1
```

Or another alternative that doesn't rely on them having the same datatype.

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as ns)
SELECT *, 
        ansCol = (SELECT x.* FOR XML PATH('row'), 
                    ELEMENTS XSINIL, TYPE).value('count(/row/*[@ns:nil])', 'int') 
FROM   t1 x
```

Answer (score 1):

This feels like a hack, and perhaps you should change your design or reduce the number of columns in your table, but if you must do this one option would be to use a subquery to get around the 10 column nested limit:

```
SELECT t.*,
       t.firstBatch + t.secondBatch AS ansCol
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        (CASE WHEN Col1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +  
         CASE WHEN Col2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +       
         ...
         CASE WHEN Col10 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS firstBatch,
        (CASE WHEN Col11 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +  
         CASE WHEN Col12 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +       
         ...
         CASE WHEN Col20 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS secondBatch
    FROM yourTable
) t
```